# how to limit my rows in a mysql table and overrite new rows to insert from 1st row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

e.g:i created a logtable and i want to keep limit of rows with 1000 records
...if i insert a record after 1000 rows my row should over ride from 1st row by deleteting or what ever it is.
is der any solution in mysql

anyone plz help

Comment: Create a table with a timestamp column. Insert 1000 rows. Update the table, updating only the row with the oldest time stamp, or, if timestamps are equal, the one with the lowest id.

Comment: Please try to use proper grammar

Answer (score 0):

There is no super simple solution, but this is possible.  Basically, you need to do two things.

The first is to keep track of the order that rows are inserted into the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so this ordering needs to be included explicitly.  One simple method is an auto-incrementing id for the table.

The second is to add a trigger to `insert`.  When a new row is inserted, then this trigger will delete a row.  I would recommend that this trigger be an *after* insert trigger.

You can also do this at the application layer.  For instance, if you insert new rows using a stored procedure, then the stored procedure can do the `delete` as well as the the `insert`.

Finally, if the goal is just to get rid of older data, there are other options.  For instance, you might consider partitioning the table or scheduling a job (event) to periodically delete excess rows.

Comment: hi sir can u send me a sample example plz: In my project i  already created a table and already keep auto increment for column  id .....i can track and check, If rows reached limit 1000 then i need to update from 1 to 1000 instead of insert here i dnt want to delete any row in my table only insert and update